# Minimax in haskell

Tags: haskell, minimax

I'm trying to write a minimax function for connectfour game, here is my unfinished code

```
minimax:: RT Board ->Int
minimax (Tree board subtrees) = case subtrees of 
    []                                                                  >evaluate board (get_turn board)  
    _                                                                  ->case get_turn board of 
            Player_X                                                   ->maximum (next_socres)  
            Player_O                                                   ->minimum  (next_socres) 
 where next_socres = map evaluate (map get_board subtrees) 

--get the node from sub trees
get_board:: RT Board -> Board
get_board (Tree board subtrees) = board

--evaluate moves(not finished)
evaluate :: Board -> Player -> Int
evaluate board me'   
    |[me,me,me,Blank] `isInfixOf_e` all_stone_lines                         = 10
    |[opp,opp,opp,Blank] `isInfixOf_e` all_stone_lines                      = -10
    |otherwise                                                              = 0 
    where
        me = get_stone_of me'
        opp = opponent' me
        all_stone_lines = combine_list stones_from_rows (combine_list     stones_from_cols (combine_list stones_from_left_dias                  stones_from_right_dias))   
        stones_from_rows = map (get_from_row board) [1..board_size] 
        stones_from_cols = map (get_from_column board) [1..board_size] 
        stones_from_left_dias = map (get_from_left_diagonal board) [-(board_size-1)..(board_size-1)]
        stones_from_right_dias = map (get_from_right_diagonal board) [2..(2*board_size)]
```

I want to use map to evaluate every subtrees before it compute the whole tree, but I don't know how to use map here... And I realised that if my code compiled, it will not be a recursion. Can anyone teach me how to do?

Comment: I would try to make minimax a recursive function. i.e map over minimax and not evaluate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your implementation that are more algorithm problems than Haskell.

Minimax is a recursive algorithm, building a score by evaluating all the moves that are possible from a position, up to a certain depth (or the end of the game).

During the recursion, `Max` player is alternating with `Min` player.

From this, the `minimax` function should have the board, the maximum depth and the player type as parameter.

Something like :

```
minimax :: Board -> Int -> Bool -> Int
minimax board depth isMax = ...
```

`minimax` should also call itself on all the possible boards generated by moves. Then you apply the `maximum` or `minimum`, depending of the `isMax` parameter.

Another thing is that you are trying to recurse on a tree.
The tree that you often see in the literature is nothing more than the recursive calls of the `minimax` function.

In other words, you don't need a tree as parameter, the tree is implicitly built by successive `minimax` calls.

As a side note, while abstracting from a particular game, it may be useful to add as a parameter a function do determine if the board is representing a finished game.

Comment: Thank you. And a further question, how limit the maximum depth?

Comment: @kkkjjj you decrement `depth` parameter at each recursive call, and don't call your function anymore when you reach `0`